# Deploying Rails app to shared host(error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a ruby on rails app on my space at asmallorange.  I've followed the instructions on their site.

However, when I get to the step where I am to do a `rake db:migrate`, it requires me to do a bundle install.  No problem, so I do that.  However, when I run the bundle install I get the following:

> sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
>
> Gem::Exception: Cannot load gem at [/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/rake-10.1.1.gem] >in /home/****/****
>   An error occurred while installing rake (10.1.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.1.1'` succeeds before bundling.

I tried running `gem install rake`, but still... no luck.

Does anybody have any advice on where I may go from here?  Or even any more efficient ways to deploy this app?  Capistrano perhaps?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a number of issues here:

---

**Are you using a VPS or shared?**

This is very important, as a VPS allows you to install your own environment, whereas a shared environment is just that; shared

I would first ensure what kind of environment you're running. If you're running a shared environment:

---

**If shared, what versions of gems do they have?**

I know from experience shared environments have the worst "update cycles" going

Our old host was telling us to run `Rails 3.1`, even when `Rails 4.0` was out. Maybe your host is running out of date software?

---

**Rake**

Your core problem is you can't install [`rake`](http://rubygems.org/gems/rake)

Rake is a core Rails component, which means big problems. It sounds to me like your host does not support the latest version of Rake, which will have all sorts of problem down the line

Personally, I would recommend using [Heroku](http://heroku.com) to get your app into a staging environment, then look at different Rails-centric solutions as your app grows

Comment: Thanks, Rich.  I checked my rake version and I have 10.1.1, where my host is on 10.1.0.  In other words to get this to work I would probably have to move down to rake 10.1.0?  Thanks!

Comment: I think that will be the case :) Although I believe Rake is a core dependency of Rails, so that would probably mean downgrading your V of Rails instead of rake itself. Hope this helps?